# Energy function for a newtonian particle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy

I am looking at the following exercise:

Find the energy function for a newtonian particle that moves on the graph of a $C^2(\mathbb{R}^{n-1})$ function in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

$$$$

The energy is the sum of the kinetic and the potencial energy.

The kinetic energy is defined as $KE = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$ and the potencial energy is defined as $PE = mgx$, right?

So, is the energy functioon equal to $E=KE+PE=\frac{1}{2}mv^2+mgx$ ?

Comment: -1. Not clear to those of us who are physicists but not mathematicians. In simple English, are you saying that the particle is confined to a closed curve in n-dimensional space in which there is a 1-dimensional uniform gravitational field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call $(q_1,\cdots,q_{n-1},q_n)$ the coordinates of the particle, where $q_i = q_i(t)$. At any time the particle is moving on the graph of a function of the form $q_n = f(q_1,\cdots, q_{n-1})$, where $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^{n-1})$, that is, the coordinates of the particle are of the form

$$
{\bf q} = \left(q_1,\cdots,q_{n-1}, f(q_1,\cdots, q_{n-1})\right)
$$

The kinetic energy is given by

\begin{eqnarray}
T &=& \frac{m}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n \dot{q}_k^2 = \frac{m}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \dot{q}_k^2 + \frac{m}{2}\left(\frac{{\rm d}f}{{\rm d}t}\right)^2 \\
&=& \frac{m}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \dot{q}_k^2  + \frac{m}{2}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial q_k}\dot{q}_k\right)^2 = \frac{m}{2}\sum_{k}^{n-1} \dot{q}_k^2  + \frac{m}{2}\sum_{k,l=1}^{n-1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial q_k}\frac{\partial f}{\partial q_l}\dot{q}_k\dot{q}_l \\
&=& \frac{m}{2}\sum_{k,l=1}^{n-1}\dot{q}_k f_{kl} \dot{q}_{l} \tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}

where

$$
f_{kl} = \delta_{kl} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial q_k}\frac{\partial f}{\partial q_l}
$$

The potential energy is a lot simpler

$$
V = mg f(q_1,\cdots,q_{n-1}) \tag{2}
$$

The energy of the particle is

$$
E  = T + V
$$